# How To Make a spoolind Directory as Sink in Flume

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I know how to make a spool directory as source in flume. I am using spool directory to copy files from a folder to hdfs sink.
Is there a way I can make spool directory as sink also so that I can copy some of my files to a local folder?

Answer (score 0):

The File Roll Sink writes events to files on the local file system. The directory to which the events should be written is specified by the sink.directory parameter.

```
#file_roll sink properties
a1.sinks = s1
a1.sinks.s1.type = file_roll
a1.sinks.s1.sink.directory = /path/to/file
```

Find the complete documentation about this sink [here](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#file-roll-sink).